# How to take out all rows that are not between two dates?

Tags: php, mysql, database, date

For example I have two columns in my DB:

Date1 and Date2. I put into my input fields (field1 = 12/11/14 and field2 = 22/11/14). So I want to take all rows into my table who have lower date than `12/11/14` and higher than `22/11/14`. How should my query look?

I will make my question more clear.

Here is my DB:

[image]

So I put into `rent_date` a client who will rent a car from `11/12/14` and will return it at `11/22/14`. There are 5 clients and only one will rent a car between exactly `11/12/14` and `11/22/14` so I want to select the other 4 clients who doesn't rent car between this two dates. I hope I was clear. :)

Comment: show the schema of the table with the data types.

Comment: I edited my question i hope i made it more clear :)

Comment: I still don't understand the question, even after seeing the expected answer. Do you want people who didn't have a car at all during this period, or didn't rent a car during that period?

Comment: People who didnt rent car during this period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to find out the records whose rent and return dates are not in the given range, you can use a query by comparing the `date`S as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM DB WHERE rent_date < '2014-11-12 00:00:00' OR return_date > '2014-11-22 23:59:59'
```

Comment: If you're looking for people who didn't rent a car during this period, shouldn't both ends use `rent_date`? What if I rented a car on '2014-11-23'?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just use the `BETWEEN` operator to check that the rent_date is not between your intervals, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE rent_date NOT BETWEEN '2014-11-12' AND '2014-11-22'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a range query.

```
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE timestamp BETWEEN timestamp1 AND timestamp2
```